# DataGrid virtualization bound to ListCollectionView with GroupDescriptions

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

As the title says, I have a WPF DataGrid bound to a ListViewCollection. The dataset is large, but the thing loads very quickly - thanks to virtualization of the rows.

However, as soon as I add a grouping, the thing starts loading every row (I can see from the wpf debug messages), leaving me twiddling my thumbs and eating all the ram.

This is mentioned here: http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/11/22/icollectionview-explained/

Specifically the bit that says "Grouping will disable the Virtualization support by default. So grouping for large data sets could be really expensive, think it twice before doing it…"

Which explains a lot, but does anyone know how to override the "by default" bit in that sentence? Should I be using something else altogether?

Comment: DataGridView is supposed to be good for large datasets:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613394/wpf-datagrid-vs-windows-forms-datagridview

Comment: Thanks, Caroline, but I'd rather stick with a wpf solution since the rest of the project uses wpf. Unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

There is probably no convenient solution with framework 4.0 See [WPF DataGrid Virtualization with Grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477044/wpf-datagrid-virtualization-with-grouping).

You can flatten the list and create your own grouping (are they kidding?) Grouping and Virtualization http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Grouping-and-Virtualization-56e7d3fe

It seems that there is a solution in framework 4.5 see:

> **Improved performance when displaying large sets of grouped data**
>
> UI virtualization occurs when a subset of user interface (UI) elements
>   are generated from a larger number of data items based on which items
>   are visible on the screen. The  VirtualizingPanel defines the 
>   IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping attached property that enables UI
>   Virtualization for grouped data. For more information about grouping
>   data, see How to: Sort and Group Data Using a View in XAML. For more
>   information about virtualizing grouped data, see the 
>   IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping attached property. (From What's New in WPF Version 4.5 which is no longer available*emphasized text*)

Comment: I realize this post is old, but the last link is broken!

Comment: @ThyArtIsCode: I have rescued the text from search engine cache.