# how can be add WPF DataGrid in Windows Form?

Tags: wpf, winforms, wpfdatagrid

I am working on a datagrid in WPF and I want to add this datagrid in Winforms.
How can this be done?

All suggestions are welcome, thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can.  WPF and WinForms are two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/integrating-wpf-in-winforms-in-vs-2010/). This shows how to implemenet a wpf project in Win Forms.

Answer (score 1):

In WinForms use ElementHost and add your WPF control inside (Best practice here is to create a WPF User Control and add you controls into the user control)

And in WPF, if you want to use a WinForms user control, use the WindowsFormsHost

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970688.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751565.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754008.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761.aspx

here is an videos example for you.

http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/danielmoth/use-wpf-from-windows-forms-projects-in-visual-studio-2008

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613394/wpf-datagrid-vs-windows-forms-datagridview). It explains the two controls (Datagrid in WPF and DatagridView in Winforms). It behaves more or less the same, but has a different framework in the background.