# Enable datagridview in vs2012?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

How do I enable DataGridView?

Currently it is greyed out in the toolbox, see this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHZD5.jpg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview) is a Windows Forms control, as your screenshot shows. Putting WinForms in WPF is usually avoided where possible as they are different technologies - you should aim to use a WPF equivalent.

If you **really** want to use it, you can use a [`WindowsFormsHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost) - there are lots of guides out there to explain how.

---

In fact, `DataGrid` **is** the WPF equivalent of `DataGridView`, e.g. [*WPF DataGrid Vs Windows Forms DataGridView*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4613394/1364007). I'd use `DataGrid` if I were using WPF.